# PHP file download header

Tags: php, file, download, header

I have developed a small download system in PHP, where files are downloaded through a proxy file. When I had to do this before, I just redirected by changing the location header; which is not what I want to do now.

So, obviously, the first issue that appeared is what kind of header must I set. First of all, `Content-Disposition` is set as "attachment", so this is good, but I can't seem to get around `Content-Type`. I need to set it to fit all possible files that might be downloaded through this system. I don't know how to detect the file header automatically, and I'm trying to aviod a GIANT `switch`. **What are my options?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was an old function `mime_content_type` that would provide the value for you.  It has been replaced with [Fileinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php).

```
 $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);
 header("Content-Type: ".finfo_file($finfo, $filename));
```